# How to display customer attributes in a drop down list using a custom module

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom tab in admin which I need to manage customer attributes.

I would like to load all customer attributes in that section and keep a check box against each attribute.

Such that when ever a check box is checked or unchecked, based on the selection, the columns will be displayed/hidden in Manage Customer Grid.

I would like to know how do I get to display all customer attributes in that section with a checkbox each?

Comment: When I say customer attributes, I mean the Attribute labels like Name, Telephone, Email, etc. I want all these attributes in a drop down list. Just like we can have attributes for products, I need it for Customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getAttributes()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Customer/Mage_Customer_Model_Customer.html#getAttributes) which returns an array of [`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Eav/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute.html).

```
<?php
$attributes = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attr) :
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="attributes[]" value="<?php echo $attr->getId() ?>" id="attribute-<?php echo $attr->getId() ?>" />
    <label for="attribute-<?php echo $attr->getId() ?>"><?php echo $attr->getStoreLabel() ?></label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

#### Much improved technique for config:

First we need to create a source model in your module, in the following you obviously have to rename it to match your *actual* module.

```
class Your_Module_Model_Source_Customer_Attribute
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $attributes = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_attribute_collection')
            // remove filter to allow default address ID, etc.
            ->addVisibleFilter();
        $result = array();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            if (($label = $attribute->getFrontendLabel()))
                $result[$attribute->getId()] = $label;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then we need a single new field in your module's **system.xml**.

```
<fieldname translate="label">
    <label>Customer Attributes</label>
    <frontend_type>checkboxes</frontend_type>
    <source_model>yourmodule/source_customer_attribute</source_model>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
</fieldname>
```

This works surprisingly well, surprising because these classes are not used in the core. Instead of `checkboxes` the type can also be `radios`, that works too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try your code but just before that would ask you one more thing.
How do I display this checkbox with attribute label in my admin section's pop-up widget form. Right now I have created a tab in admin area with a section to manage customer attributes.
The pop up form has just a text box for now. I would like these checkboxes to be displayed in that form so how will system.xml understand that these checkboxes are supposed to be outputted in my admin section?

Comment: 1)I get many black checkboxes with no labels at all. how to get rid of that?

Comment: 2)They are getting echoed right at the top of the page in my admin area. I want them to be displayed in the pop-up widget form for the new section that I have created. How to do that?

Comment: Also I created another array to retrieve customer's address attributes having the same code just by replacing ('customer/customer') with ('customer/address') but again why so many blank checkboxes with no label?

Please do reply back. I am finally getting some where with this, thanks to you.

Comment: I didn't realise you meant to use the configuration section. There might be a sly workaround using `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Checkboxes` but it's not something I ever tried before. I will give it a go now...

Comment: Ok please let me know once you have done.Because I have tried a couple of things. Dint really work. And I don't know how to use this Varien_Data_Form_Element_Checkboxes. Please let me know.

Comment: It turned out to be very simple.

Comment: Ok Il try that as well..Thanks

Comment: Great! That worked like a charm. But If I want to show all teh attributes including the address collection(City,Country,Postcode,Company,etc) then what should I do?
I am guessing its got something to do with changing the getModel() line

Comment: Those attributes are from a separate entity, the customer address. You'll have to find a way of adding them to `$result` in the source model in whichever order you need them in.

Comment: Do you know how to access the customer address entity like what do you call it?
I was thinking of maybe repeating the same procedure but for address collection and then appending it to the $result value.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it but with a `'customer/entity_address_attribute_collection'` model.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Now just trying to figure out how to add it to $result. So that I have all the attributes with checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

That's the final code. Obviously BIG thanks to you for your help with the code at the first place.

```
    $attributes = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_address_attribute_collection');
    $result = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
    {
        if (($label = $attribute->getFrontendLabel()))
            $result[$attribute->getId()] = $label;
    }
    $attributes1 = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_attribute_collection');
    $result1 = array();
    foreach ($attributes1 as $attribute1)
    {
        if (($label1 = $attribute1->getFrontendLabel()))
            $result1[$attribute1->getId()] = $label1;
    }
    $final = array_merge($result, $result1);

    return $final;
```